# How to run multi domainname in one django with nginx and uwsgi

Tags: python, django, nginx

I want to use multi domain for one django project

one domain name for one app

now my project like this

```
test.com/        -> Homepage
test.com/appa    -> App A
test.com/appb    -> App B
```

I want to change to

```
www.test.com    -> Homepage
appa.test.com   -> App A
appb.test.com   -> App B
```

I think I can use nginx virtual host to solve this problem

but now I have no idea

pleas help me.

now I use rewrite it works but not pretty good

nginx

```
server {
    ...

    server_name domain2

    ...

    location / {
        rewrite / /app1/
        ...
    }
}
```

when I browse  domain2/

it can redirect to domain2/app1/

but i want domain2/ as /app1/

Answer (score 1):

finally I use proxy_pass to solve this

```
http://site.localhost/app1/        => http://app1.site.localhost/
http://site.localhost/app1/test/   => http://app1.site.localhost/test/
http://site.localhost/app2/        => http://app2.site.localhost/
http://site.localhost/app2/test/   => http://app2.site.localhost/test/
```

by

```
server {
    ...  # no changes
    location / {
        # no changes
    }
}

# app1.site.localhost proxy to 127.0.0.1/app1
server {
    server_name app1.site.localhost;
    location = / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/app1$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nginx can work with multiple domains using the **server** namespace

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.org  www.example.org;
    ...
}
```

you can set multiple servers (best practice as multiple files) and multiple **upstream** as so

```
upstream uwsgi {
  server unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;
}
```

so each server will invoked by different domain and pass the request to different uwsgi process (aka different django app)

An example Nginx configuration can look like this, keep in mind that you will need multiple uwsgi process, one for each app

```
upstream uwsg_app_a {
  server unix:///tmp/uwsg_app_b.sock;
}

upstream uwsg_app_b {
  server unix:///tmp/uwsg_app_a.sock;
}


server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.test.com;

    location / {
        root /homapge/static;
    }
 }

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  appa.test.com;

    location / {
      uwsgi_pass uwsg_app_a;
    }
 }

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  appb.test.com;

    location / {
      uwsgi_pass uwsg_app_b;
    }
}
```

Comment: do I need add new sock in uwsgi for upstream to use?

Comment: it depends, if you are using multiple django apps , you need a uwsgi process for each of them thus need a separate socket for each uwsgi, the answer above is a draft implementation and you should read the Nginx, uwsgi documentation for a specific code for your use case

Comment: Is your example  for one domain?
I create two server in my nginx for two domain

Comment: can nginx  set alias  domain/ = domain/app ?

Comment: I edit my answer to match your changes and address your new questions
alias is used to pass from one location to another you can see the following doc http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias
rewrite is also possible, but the best practice is to use return 301 so you can use `return 301 http://www.anotherdomain.com$request_uri;`

Answer (score 0):

For the uwsgi solution, if you plan to host several uwsgi applications, have a look at [uwsgi emperor](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Emperor.html).

It uses, a vassals folder, in which it must be placed the configuration file for each uwsgi application you host. For example in:
`/etc/uwsgi/vassals`

in order to update an application, you don't need to stop|start uwsgi, just using the command:
`touch --no-dereference /etc/uwsgi/vassals/any-web-app.ini`

A sample of vassal config:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /opt/apps/myapp
threads = 20
; bind to the socket
socket = /tmp/sockets/myapp.sock
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myapp.settings
module = django.core.handlers.wsgi:WSGIHandler()
; privileges
uid = foo
gid = bar
```

It reduces general RAM consumption than using separated uwsgi commands. The threads work the same way, being able to select a number of processes for each application.

Regarding nginx, the upstream approach mentioned in a previous post works great, and much faster using unix like sockets.
Further help on nginx upstream configurations for nginx can be found in [this anchor](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html) of the uwsgi docs